# How to get a last business day of a month with `business_time` gem

Tags: ruby

I want to get a last day of a month by using `business_time` gem.

This code works if the first day of the month is a business day.

```
1.business_day.before(Date.parse("2014-12-01"))
```

But if the first day is not a business day, it returns a day earlier like this:

```
1.business_day.before(Date.parse("2014-11-01"))  # => 2014-10-30 (It should be 2014-10-31)
```

How can I get a last business day of a month by ruby?
If necessary I'll use another gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a gem, really

```
require 'time'

def last_business_day date
  day = Date.parse(date).next_month
  loop do
    day = day.prev_day
    break unless day.saturday? or day.sunday?
  end
  day
end

last_business_day '2014-11-01' # => '2014-11-28'
last_business_day '2014-12-01' # => '2014-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

install the gem `week_of_month`

In IRB try:

```
   require 'week_of_month'

   date = Date.parse("2014-11-01")

   date.end_of_month.downto(date).find{|day| day.working_day? }
   => #<Date: 2014-11-28 ((2456990j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Without `week_of_month`, just replace `day.working_day?` by `day.wday.in? 1..5`

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a modified version of Sachin's response that uses the Holiday gem to take into consideration US holidays.

```
# lib/holidays/business_day_helpers.rb
require 'holidays'

module Holidays
  module BusinessDayHelpers
    def business_day?(calendar = :federal_reserve)
      !holiday?(calendar) && !saturday? && !sunday?
    end

    def last_business_day_of_the_month(calendar = :federal_reserve)
      end_of_month.downto(beginning_of_month).find(&:business_day?)
    end

    def last_business_day_of_the_week(calendar = :federal_reserve)
      end_of_week.downto(beginning_of_week).find(&:business_day?)
    end
  end
end

Date.include Holidays::BusinessDayHelpers
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with `business_time` gem:

```
Time.previous_business_day(Date.parse("2014-12-01") - 1.day)
```